# Interactive map solution suggestions

Tags: php, asp.net, javascript, flash, actionscript-3

I'm looking to browser based map solution like [google interactive chart map](http://code.google.com/intl/tr-TR/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/geomap.html).  I googled and i looked to smilar solution, but i didn't find good solution for it. It should be possible to created on flash, silverlight, ajax etc.

And should be change parameters easyly via javascript or sth. But i didn't like google chart beacuse; you can't change background of map and you can't modify tooltips.

Do you have any suggestions about it ?

Answer (score 1):

Be practical, use Google. Don't be *that* guy.

Comment: I agree with you, but you should consider my question, you can't change tooltip or background on google chart or map.

Answer (score 0):

Download or use the web based version of [Tour de Flex](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex) (application for exploring flex capabilities)

Look for the folder Mapping, it gives you four options

-ESRI ArcGS

-Google Maps

-MapQuest Maps

-Yahoo Maps

Tool tip overlay examples are available for Google Maps. I have no clue what you mean by changing the background.... the map is the background. oO (please clarify)

Answer (score 0):

Try [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com). It works faster than Google implementation, looks nicer and has more built-in maps.